# not able to see recovery mode on my Redmi1s after I installed cyanogemod 11

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, cyanogenmod, xiaomi

After I installed cyanogenmod 11 on my new redmi 1s using clockworkmod recovery. I found that I am not able to see the recovery screen as the mi boot time logo is hiding the recovery screen.Can any one help me???
I have followed [this](http://webtrickz.com/how-to-install-android-4-4-4-kitkat-based-cm11-rom-on-xiaomi-redmi-1s/) tutorial.Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Boot time logo cannot hide the recovery. Try to reinstall [recovery from fastboot](http://forum.xda-developers.com/redmi-1s/orig-development/recovery-cwm-philz-touch-t2845710):

```
fasboot flash recovery clockworkmod_recovery.img
```